# Unable to call broker - MSAL for Android

Tags: android, azure-ad-msal

**Problem**
App using latest MSAL for Android version is unable to call broker to sign-in.
Followed the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-android-single-sign-on#:%7E:text=%20There%20are%20two%20ways%20for%20applications%20using,for%20benefits%20like%20device-wide%20SSO%2C%20account...%20More%20) to use MSAL for the app.

I have already check we are using the latest MSAL version, and the config JSON file, package name in code are all set correctly including the "redirect URI, broker_redirect_uri_registered.
Broker (Microsoft Company Portal) has already installed and and signed in. The device is compliant.

As I know, MSAL for Android will call broker to sign-in by default.
Any ideas why the app using MSAL is unable to call broker?

**Expected behavior**
The app should call broker and sign in by default.

**Actual Behavior**
The app will request the user to download broker(Microsoft Company portal) even the user has downloaded the app on the device. Therefore, users are unable to pass device-based conditional access policy during sign-in.

**More Context**
AndroidManifest.xml

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <!--
            Add in your scheme/host from registered redirect URI
            note that the leading "/" is required for android:path
        -->
        <data
            android:host="com.imobilemind.isaicloud"
            android:path="/hfy+7NbfbffwKZ9tqUkBtXgkJcE="
            android:scheme="msauth" />
        
    </intent-filter>`
```

Config file

```
{ "client_id" : "1540d24d-479b-4edb-9c98-971415582d29", "authorization_user_agent" : "DEFAULT", "redirect_uri" : "msauth://com.imobilemind.isaicloud/hfy%2B7NbfbffwKZ9tqUkBtXgkJcE%3D", "account_mode" : "SINGLE", "broker_redirect_uri_registered": true, "authorities" : [ { "type": "AAD", "default": true, "audience": { "type": "AzureADMyOrg", "tenant_id": "305675df-dc39-4b66-8034-b8e7a8cXXXXXX" } } ] }
```

Comment: Your manifest file and Config File looks fine. For more details you can please check code samples from [this](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android) link.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. We found the issue may be realted to the api permission.

We test the sample code. When we add the same api permission to the sample app, it also encountered the same issue. (It is to say that the root cause may not be related to their package.)

Since the api permission is another app also registered in AAD and will authnticated with AAD, I am wondering if that resource app need addtional configuration to let the client call borker and get the device info?

Comment: @EmilyWen Were you able to make it work? If so, please explain what you did.